# Setting an Animation to a Sprite Node

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, sprite-kit

I got some code from the apple developer site on textures which includes the following :

```
Character *character = [Character spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"Obstacle03.png"];
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"character"];
SKTexture *a1 = [atlas textureNamed:@"Obstacle.png"];
SKTexture *a2 = [atlas textureNamed:@"Obstacle02.png"];
SKTexture *a3 = [atlas textureNamed:@"Obstacle03.png"];
SKTexture *a4 = [atlas textureNamed:@"Obstacle04.png"];
NSArray *characterWalkTextures = @[a1,a2,a3,a4];
SKAction *characterAnimate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:characterWalkTextures timePerFrame:0.5];
[self runAction:characterAnimate];
```

But instead of the character node looping through a set of textures, the node just shows up as a box with a red x inside. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the textures are not being loaded. this is why you are getting the box with red x inside.

Comment: Thanks how exactly would I do that

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases